# lodash ._find is not working for some variable though it is a string

Tags: reactjs, lodash

I have an array like this.

```
 const  countries = [
{ "name": "CSS", "value": 'css',"id":['1','2','3']},
{ "name": "HTML", "value": 'HTML',"id":['11','21','31']},
{ "name": "JavaScript", "value": 'JavaScript',"id":['12','22','32']},
{ "name": "Ruby on Rails", "value": 'ror',"id":['12','22','32']},
]
```

Now after some manipulation, I am trying to do this.

```
    checkCountry(evt){
    var test = JSON.stringify(evt).replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
    console.log("value  " + test  )
    var selectedCountry = _.find(countries, { 'value':test})
    console.log("print selected country " + selectedCountry)
}
```

In console, I am getting the value ,

```
    value  "css"
    print selected country undefined
```

But if do something like this,

```
    checkCountry(evt){
    var selectedCountry = _.find(countries, { 'value':"css"})
    console.log("print selected country " + selectedCountry)
}
```

I am getting response!! 
Please advise!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your literal string is `"css"`, and you should be searching for `css`. You have to remove the double quotes.

```
.replace(/[\[\]'"]+/g,'')
```

Comment: @treena Sometimes what is needed is just another pair of eyes :) Happens to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your RegExp isn't correct. 
Try this one `/[\[\]'"]+/g` here:

```
...
var test = JSON.stringify(evt).replace(/[\[\]'"]+/g,'');
...
```